# Something destroying my flower garden and potted plants

Tags: pests

All of my flowers, including my potted ones, are being dug into at the roots but the flowers are not being eaten.  What do I do?

Comment: Need more info - photographs maybe, but at least where you are in the world.

Comment: Hi and welcome! As you can see, we need more details in order to give you good answers.  If you [edit](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/19289/edit) anything specific you can think of into your question, I'm sure someone will help you!